# cordova readAsText returns json string that can't be parsed to JSON object

Tags: json, cordova

I read my json file using http and cordova file readAsText functions.

http request returns an object which is ok.

cordova file readAsText function return 'string' which contain extra "r\n\" symbols. This make it impossible to use JSON.parse(evt.target.result)

```
function readJson(absPath, success, failed){
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(absPath, function (entry) {
            entry.file(function (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                    success(evt.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, failed);
        }, failed);
}

readJson(cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'my.json', function(res){
    console.log(JSON.parse(res));  //here I've got an parsing error due to presence of r\n\ symbols
}, failed );
```

How to read JSON files using cordova?

**UPDATE:**

funny thing that the following works:

```
a = '{\r\n"a":"1",\r\n"b":"2"\r\n}';
b = JSON.parse(a);
```

so the problem not only with \r\n... there is something else that is added by cordova readAsText

**UPDATE2**

as a workaround I use now `var object = eval("(" + res + ")")`

Still search for a common way to load json objects...

Comment: And if you do: JSON.parse(res.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, ''))

Comment: I've tried that and this gives the same "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" while parsing

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

No one has answered this and I just had to solve it for my project, so I will post my solution.

The readAsText method outputs a string, so you CAN actually run a replace on it, but what you need to do is use a RegExp to find the newline character. here's my solution:

```
 var sanitizerRegex = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(10), 'g');
 var sanitizedData = JSON.parse(result.replace(sanitizerRegex, ''));
```

I've used the String method fromCharCode to get the specific newline character and the "g" flag to match all instances in the entire string. The problem with your string solution is that you can't do a string replace using the characters for backslash and "n" because the issue is the actual new line character, which is merely represented as "\n".

I do not know the reason JSON.parse can't handle the newline character, or why the file plugin introduces this problem, but this solution seems to work for me.

Also, NEVER use eval like this if you can avoid it, especially on input from a source like a JSON file. Even in a cordova app, using eval is potentially very unsafe.

Comment: I would upvote this twice, if I could. Once for the slick answer using `fromCharCode()` and once for saying "NEVER use eval like this if you can avoid it, especially on input from a source"

It would be polite of [31415926] (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913629/31415926) to mark this as the correct answer, it sure as hell is the best idea I've seen.

Comment: I also got same problem after read json file, can't parse {'name':'John'}
SyntaxError: Unexcepted token

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution after debug deeply. `readAsText` function returned text has one more letter at the first position of text.

Example:

{"name":"John"} => ?{"name":"John"} (?: API didn't return ?, just one string)

I confirmed this with length of result, so we need to use substr(1) before parse JSON.

```
fileContent = fileContent.substr(1);
var jData = jQuery.parseJSON(fileContent);
```